# System.out compiler error

Tags: java, jdbc, system.out

I'm using Linux text editor and compiling via terminal. I've come across a weird  problem where I'm getting compiler errors on a simple `System.out.println`.

Here is my code. I am trying to implement JDBC on a localhost database:

```
import java.sql.*;

class DatabaseConnection {

final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb";

final String user = "root";
final String pass = "pass";

Connection connection;
Statement statement;

public DatabaseConnection(){

}

public void connect(){
    try {
        //Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);           
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, user, pass);
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("show tables");

        while(resultSet.next()){
            System.out.println(resultSet.toString());
        }
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        sqle.getErrorCode();
    }

}

     /*empty methods beyond this point*/

}
```

My test class to try out the new functionality:

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello");
        DatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection();
        connection.connect();
    }

}
```

When compiling in terminal I get the following errors:

```
user@user ~/Desktop/Java/JavaSE_Project $ javac Test.java 
Test.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
    System.out.println("Hello");
          ^
 symbol:   variable out
 location: class System
 ./DatabaseConnection.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
            System.out.println("hello");
                  ^
 symbol:   variable out
 location: class System
 2 errors
```

I understand my logic isn't quite right as of yet but I'm honestly dumbstruck as to why it's doing this.

Java version:

```
java version "1.7.0_95"
 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.4) (7u95-2.6.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.2)
 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Any chance you got some import of another `System` class?

Comment: schoolboy error. I called the class which contains my main method in the actual program "System". 

Post as an answer and I'll point you up. Thanks for pointing out the obvious!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per request: supposedly strange errors of that kind often are a matter of conflicting/wrong imports as seemed to be the case here, i.e. a class `System` in the same package.

Another case which we often ran into was `com.ibm.icu.math.BigDecimal` vs. `java.math.BigDecimal`.

Comment: A System.java/System.class on the class path or lying in the same directory was my idea too.

Answer (score 2):

This can only happens because of these two reasons.

1. Either `java.sql.*` package contains any `System` Class.

OR

2. Any already user defined `System` Class already exists in your `Package`.

Comment: No 3 can't happen if the class is not inside a package and is not imported explicitly.